# Changing border color in mat-form-field

Tags: css, angular

I am using angular material `mat-form-field`. I have a dark background, and therefore am trying to change the border of the form-field to white. But I am not able to achieve it using css. No, matter what changes I do in the css, they are not reflecting back into the `mat-form-field`. Here is the link to my code:

[StackBlitz link to my work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnzlr5)

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Add this CSS to your *form-field-appearance-example.css*:

```
/* Border */
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: white;
}
/* Font color */
input.mat-input-element {
  color: white;
}
```

Though, there is still a problem while the field is focused.

Comment: Hi, thanks. It works. May I know how did you find these classes, I was not able to find these classes in the developer tools.

Comment: Glad to hear :) I just stepped through the HTML with the [Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector). However, it is quite a little hassle to change the CSS of Angular Material.

Comment: ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline:not(.mat-form-field-outline-thick) {
    color: #c5c5c5;
  }

helped to me to segregate thin and thick border

Comment: how can i change the label color

Comment: Works but does not limited to a scope

Answer (score 72):

I think this will cover everything.

```
// mat-icon-stepper selected color change 
::ng-deep .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected, .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-state-done, .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-state-edit {
    background-color: red!important;
}

//input outline color
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: red!important;
    // opacity: 1!important;
}

//mat-input focused color
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
    color: red!important;
}

// mat-input error outline color
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-invalid.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-outline-thick{
    color: red!important;
    opacity: 0.8!important;
}

// mat-input carent color
::ng-deep .mat-input-element {
    caret-color: red!important;
}

// mat-input error carent color
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-invalid .mat-input-element, .mat-warn .mat-input-element {
    caret-color: red!important;
}

// mat-label normal state style
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.6)!important;
    // color: $mainColor!important;
}

// mat-label focused style
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
    color: red!important;
}

// mat-label error style
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-label {
    color: red!important;
}
```

Comment: defenetly complete solution, instead of `!important` i added container class

Comment: Nice to have would be to replace the color `red` with a css variable, so the color changes everywhere without updating a hundred locations

Comment: Should be enough to write `::ng-deep` just once, in case of scss

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i was looking for something like which has complete explanation on changing border and all other detail @sasa

Comment: Note: `::ng-deep` is being [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: @dilantha111 no is not, `::ng-deep` is being deprecated as @pistol-pete said too

Comment: ::ng-deep deprecated

Answer (score 17):

For the newer outlined form fields, solved it this way:

```
::ng-deep {
     .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
        color: white;
     }
     mat-form-field {
        .mat-hint, input, ::placeholder, .mat-form-field-label {
           color: white;
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: I came upon your answer, and hadn't realized that "::ng-deep" specifically told it to look past the declared elements (which would not include the label inside the `div` element) until I had a co-worker explain why I needed it.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Just FYI, `::ng-deep` is deprecated and should be avoided when possible. https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: @Rich But it seems there is no other way to override the view encapsulation. So there is no other option than using `::ng-deep`

Comment: You should theme your angular-mat components inside your styles.scss, where you don't need `ng-deep`, and makes your changes generic to any components using it.

Comment: @Random only if you intend to use the new style everywhere

Comment: @btx indeed, that's the goal of Angular Material, making the design generic in your app. If you need a specific styling, you may add a class to your specific component, and style it in your styles.scss (i.e. `mat-formfield.no-hint-space { ...}`, where you would be able to reuse this specific style.

Answer (score 11):

`SCSS` version of @sasa with colors as variables

```
::ng-deep {
   $custom-main-color: red;
   $custom-label-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);

   // mat-icon-stepper selected color change
   .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected, .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-state-done, .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-state-edit {
      background-color: $custom-main-color !important;
   }

   // input outline color
   .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
      color: $custom-main-color !important;
   }

   // mat-input focused color
   .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
      color: $custom-main-color !important;
   }

   // mat-input error outline color
   .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-invalid.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
      color: $custom-main-color !important;
      opacity: 0.8 !important;
   }

   // mat-input caret color
   .mat-input-element {
      caret-color: $custom-main-color !important;
   }

   // mat-input error caret color
   .mat-form-field-invalid .mat-input-element, .mat-warn .mat-input-element {
      caret-color: $custom-main-color !important;
   }

   // mat-label normal state style
   .mat-form-field-label {
      color: $custom-label-color !important;
   }

   // mat-label focused style
   .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
      color: $custom-main-color !important;
   }

   // mat-label error style
   .mat-form-field.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-label {
      color: $custom-main-color !important;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I had tried many things, finally, I am able to change the bottom line (which we are thinking is a border, which is actually not a border), using this:

```
::ng-deep.mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple{
    background-color: black;
}
```

That colored line is actually span filled with color! Hope this helps :)

Comment: exactly what i was looking for,tysm!

Answer (score 7):

After upgrading to Angular 15/16, this seems to work for outline "notched" style inputs, allowing default theme for focus and error states. Requires `!important` to override default styling without touching the theme

scss:

```
.mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--invalid):not(.mdc-text-field--focused):not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) {
  .mdc-notched-outline > * {
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2) !important;
  }
}
```

html (note `appearance='outline'`):

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>bleh</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="bleh" />
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.bleh.hasError('required')">don't forget bleh, bruh</mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked for me (Angular 16)

Answer (score 4):

HTML

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="margin: 0 20px;" class="border-red">
     <mat-label>Transaction Number</mat-label>
     <input matInput placeholder="Transaction number" [(ngModel)]="transactionNumber">
</mat-form-field>
```

SCSS

```
$color-outline: red;

mat-form-field {
   &.border-red {
      // to change border color
      ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline {
           color: $color-outline !important;
      }
      // to change label color
      ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label {
           color: $color-outline !important;
      }
   }
}
```

this will work only if you give `.border-red` class to your `mat-form-field`.

If you want to apply on all mat-form-field (remove border-red style rule)

```
$color-outline: red;

mat-form-field {
      // to change border color
      ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline {
           color: $color-outline !important;
      }
      // to change label color
      ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label {
           color: $color-outline !important;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Solution using CSS is so simple. I investigated the element in google developer tools. The best solution is the following code. I just wanted to change the border color in case of the input element is valid:

**the following codes are for the style.css file**

```
.ng-valid div {
    color: #009e08 !important;
 }
```

This solution will change the color of the text also. If you don't want to change the color of the text you can adjust the color of the text by the following CSS code:

```
.ng-valid div input {
  color: black !important;
}
```

Of course you can choose the color you want.

You can use the following to change the color of the border of the input if it is not touched before

To change the color of the thin border:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline{
   color: black:
}
```

To change the color of the thick border that appears on hover:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-thick{
    color: #3f51b5 !important
}
```

however, these CSS rules, override the red color appears if the input field is not valid. To prevent this you can use the following CSS rules:
For the thin border:

```
.mat-form-field-outline:not( .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-invalid.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-outline-thick){
    color: black;
}
```

For the thick border:
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-thick:not( .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-invalid.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-outline-thick){
color: #3f51b5 !important
}

If you want to use these rules in the CSS file of the component, then you may need to add `::ng-deep` before each rule.

Comment: Workable solution, but it changes the color of text also that I don't want.

Comment: I updated the solution. You can separately adjust the color of the text.

Answer (score 1):

remove boder and add box-shadow :

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
        border-radius: 50% !important;
        border: none;
        border-left: none;
    }
    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start {
        border-radius: 1px !important;
        border: none;
        border-right: none;
    }
    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
        border-radius: 1px !important;
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    
    ::ng-deep.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
        box-shadow: -5px -5px 20px #fff, 5px 5px 20px #babecc;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add css to the global styles.scss file , it works when placed there .

I have used this css in styles.scss and it has worked for me -

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: black;
  }
```

I hope this would help others .

Comment: This is the cleanest answer. `ng-deep` deprecated and not a good practice anyway. This should be the answer

Comment: Not working. @hyena, Can you please share the stackBlitz link ?

Comment: @VikramSapate what stackbBlitz? I used this `.mat-form-field-error {
  border: 1px solid white !important;
}` in the styles.scss and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate solution for this problem is to access the _connectionContainerRef property of the MatFormField. Then, find the child elements using selector and apply the custom style. I highly recommend to use a Directive to solve this problem.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[adOutlineBorder]',
})
export class OutlineBorderDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() adOutlineBorder: MatFormField;
  @Input() outlineColor: string = 'none';
  @Input() outlineRadius: number = 10;
  @Input() outlineWidth: number = 3;

  constructor() {}
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const element = this.adOutlineBorder._connectionContainerRef.nativeElement.querySelector(
      '.mat-form-field-outline'
    ) as HTMLElement;
    element.style.border = `${this.outlineWidth}px solid ${this.outlineColor}`;
    element.style.borderRadius = `${this.outlineRadius}px`;
  }
}
```

```
 <mat-form-field
    #fieldRef
    [adOutlineBorder]="fieldRef"
    [outlineWidth]="3"
    [outlineColor]="'green'"
    [outlineRadius]="10"
  > </mat-form-field>
```

Modern web applications have lots of dynamic styles. It is not easy to apply styles through CSS because it seems Angular Material does not have a goal like that. I think focusing on CSS-IN-JS will have a huge impact on your applications because style will be more configurable which enhances user-experience to the greatest extend.

Answer (score 1):

mat-form-field elements add some classes when they change their state. For instance, when you click a text input, it adds `mat-focused`. You can use that, along with other selectors to change the border:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this , add/remove ::ng-deep if required

```
 ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
                border-radius: 1px !important;
                border: 1px solid  red;
                border-left:none;
              }
            ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start {
                border-radius: 1px !important;
                border: 1px solid red;
                border-right:none;
              }
              ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
                border-radius: 1px !important;
                border-bottom: 1px solid   red;
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

### **I used this method and got the answer , And that's why I share that you can use.**

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-flex {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-infix {
        padding: 0 !important;
        height: 35px;
        border: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
/** form field bottom border color */
.mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-underline::before {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything, but this works very well for me, both for focus, hover, and when it is neither

```
::ng-deep.mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-flex {
border-bottom: #BBB 1px solid;
background-color: transparent;}

::ng-deep.mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple {
background-color: rgb(51, 88, 155) !important;}

::ng-deep.mat-form-field:hover .mat-form-field-ripple {
background-color: rgb(51, 88, 155) !important;}
```