# Material Input TextBox to be Outside Red in Error Validation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

I used following links to change  color of a textbox to darkish Grey..

https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

[Changing border color in mat-form-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096529/changing-border-color-in-mat-form-field)

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: #757575!important;
}
```

However in error validation, doing this made the error outside color still remain Dark grey.
I want it to be red, Only on error validation issues.
How would someone resolve this?

**Current Result:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

Comment: can you are share you html code

Comment: The last version of material, make it for you, the only you need is change the color of input adding, e.g. `[style.color]="emailFormControl.errors && emailFormControl.touched?'red':null"` see this simple stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mibd45?file=src/app/input-error-state-matcher-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please utilize this code with `mat-form-field-invalid`

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: red!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add these to CSS

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
            color: #757575!important;
            border: 1px solid red;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-empty.mat-form-field-label {
            color: #757575;
            border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: it's a very,very,very,very bad idea use ::ng-deep