# Angular material change outline appearance of form field

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, invalidation, mat-form-field

Hi from this question [Changing border color in mat-form-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096529/changing-border-color-in-mat-form-field) I already learned how to change the caret-color of a mat-form-field in case of invalid input, but I can't figure out how to change the outline color of such.

caret example

```
.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-input-element, .mat-warn .mat-input-element {
caret-color: #fbc1c1; 
}
```

what I thought would work:

```
.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-outline, .mat-warn .mat-form-field-outline{
color: #fbc1c1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the correct css part after using tools

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-invalid.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
    color: #f44336;
}
```