# Angular8 :How to add box shadow in mat-form field outline

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular materail and I want to have a box shadow in my inputs .
I don't Know How to add box shadow in mat-form field outline.
I wrote this code but it doesn't work correctly;

```
   ::ng-deep
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused
.mat-form-field-outline-thick {
color: red;
box-shadow: 0 4px 4px red !important;
}
```

}

Comment: It does https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f4q5ej?file=src/app/form-field-error-example.css

Comment: Can you try this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096529/changing-border-color-in-mat-form-field. It may help you.