# How to set the focused border line color for mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material

The accepted answer in this post [Changing border color in mat-form-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096529/changing-border-color-in-mat-form-field) introduced how to change the border line color of `mat-form-field`. I wonder whether there is a way to change the border color when it's focused. I have tried to add following code to the `scss` file but it does not work:

```
.mat-focused .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
  /*change color of label*/
  color: green!important;
}
```

Can someone tell whether there is a way to change the focused border line color?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change this color strategy for all controls then you should visit https://material.angular.io/guide/theming. You can also make custom theme with your own colors.

In case you want for a specific control, you can do with below css

```css
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I wonder where can I find the syntax of the scss? I didn't know there should not be a space between `mat-form-field-appearance-outline` and `mat-focused`.

Comment: Though this is about simple css. Still you can learn scss from here https://sass-lang.com/guide